# Type error: Comparing an Integer and List in For Loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, error-handling

Python beginner here.
How can you solve comparing list and int error in for loop of a dictionary, please help!

```
from random import *
passenger = list(range(1,51))

timelist = []
for i in range(1,51):
    n = randint(15,51)
    timelist.append(n)
    
passenger_time = {'passenger':passenger, 'timelist':timelist}

for x in passenger_time.values():
    if 40 > x > 15:
        print('passenger {} accepted'.format(y))
    else:
        print('not accepted')
```

Comment: I think you want to inspect what `x` is when you assign it to `passenger_time.values()` -- it looks to me like the values of your dictionary are two lists. So the next line `if 40 > x > 15` doesn't make sense when x is a list.  Anyway, that's my guess, without running the code!

Comment: Please explain a) what this is *supposed* to do and b) the details of the error.

Comment: Why do you have a dictionary of lists. A list of dictionaries would probably be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you want is:

```
for pass, time in zip(passenger_times['passenger'], passenger_times['timelist']):
    if 15 < time < 40:
        print(f'passenger {pass} is accepted')
```

This iterates over the two lists in parallel. It checks the value in one of the lists, then prints the corresponding value from the other list.

Your code is just iterating over the two values in the dictionary. The first time, `x` contains the entire `passenger` list, the second time it contains the entire `timelis` list. It makes no sense to do `15 < x < 40` when `x` is a list.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please explain a little more what you're trying to do (what you're trying to compare)?

*and write your if like this:

```
if (x < 40) and (x > 15):
    ...
```

It might work in python, the way you wrote it, but you're definately going to have a problem if you're gonna use other languages

Comment: He's not using `for x in passenger_time:`, he's using `for x in passenger_times.values()` to iterate over just the values. There's no need to use `value = passenger_time[x]`.

Comment: Syntax like `15 < x < 40` is considered one of Python's nice features, there's no need to warn people away from it.

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve the problem, since `passenger_time[x]` is still a list, not a number.

Comment: As I said, its just harder when trying out new languages, thus I would always recommend the most common way of doing something

Comment: My bad, I'm not used to such oversimplified languages. They're great for learning how to code, but for everything beyond, I avoid them as much as I can